# Why does sed output all at once?

Tags: sed

I have a 500Mb file that I am trying to manipulate with sed.

Everything works fine just I noticed it reads and processes all in memory and then outputs all at once. Is this natural behavior for a file this size?

I was expecting it to output each line after finishing and continuing to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on some version of sed you can use option `-u` to work in a stream version.

AIX sed

> -u
>
> load  minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often

GNU sed

> `-u'` --unbuffered'
>
> ```
>  Buffer both input and output as minimally as practical.  (This is
>  particularly useful if the input is coming from the likes of `tail
>  -f', and you wish to see the transformed output as soon as
>  possible.)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There are different "modes" of buffering that can be used; commonly, line-buffered output is used when the output is going to a terminal (which programs can detect by `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`).  I assume you are running your sed script and repeatedly viewing the output and noticing that it sort of appears "all at once."  This doesn't mean sed is loading everything into memory--sed is a line-oriented program, and almost certainly it is processing your input line-by-line.  If the output of sed is a file, it's normal and expected for the file to be populated in big chunks, because it's more efficient this way, when nobody seems to be looking at the output (again, because isatty returns false).